# Previewing new added layer in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, layers

I got my `GeoServer` up and tried to published my `layer`.

I have my own `shapefile` and I follow the document below to add new layer intend to publish it.

[geoserver shapefile-quickstart doc](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.1.4/user/gettingstarted/shapefile-quickstart/index.html)

Referring to the document, it shows the below 4 steps:

```
1) Create New Workspace
2) Create Store
3) Create Layer
4) ***Layer Preview***
```

I am having problem on the last step: `Layer Preview`. When I access to the `Layer Preview` in `GeoServer`, I did not see my added layer in the preview list.

What could be the possible reason for the above problem?

I am new to `GIS` and new to `GeoServer`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are publishing/Editing the layer in the web interface, go to the 'Publishing Tab' and  Under `Edit layer` check the `Advertise` check box.

If this is enabled, then you should see the layer in the Layer Preview.